# Eclipse. Are there something to have www bookmarks related to project?

Tags: eclipse, bookmarks

I want to have bookmarks related to libraries,frameworks used in eclipse project. What is the best way? Only one I can imagine is to have bookmarks folders in Firefox, and nothing in build-in browser.
May be its possible to have url files in project folder, act as bookmarks, with fav icon and opened in build in browser? Then I can import them depending on frameworks used.

I mean any libraries included in project, bookmarks may be created not automatically, I can just copy/import them together with library.
Example, 3 library included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Manager</title>
    <script src="dx/dhtmlx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="dx/dhtmlx.css" />
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<style>
```

**So, in general, I need some buttons/files/anything else, what opens a webpage. And it should be easy to copy or import to project.**

Comment: Do you mean user libraries (_Window > Preferences: Java > Build Path > User Libraries_)? If not, please describe the use case using a concrete example.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. I've updated it.